Need to keep outlet hot while using switch to power new lights
I have a light switch that just powers an outlet. I'd like to keep outlet hot while using the switch for new lights. I will drop the new wiring for lights from attic down to the switch. However, upon opening up receptacle and switch box, I am not thrown off by the wiring. Does anyone have any guidance?



Just wondering if there is not a hidden junction box nearby.  Neutral should not be on switches, but the outlet seems to have neutral from the switch.

If the wiring was done right(which I doubt), you should have the whites(maybe neutrals) connected together with a wire nut at the switch. Hot and switch hot to power the outlet.

Need a better pics of the switch (front and back) as there are more wires than normal. And what's up with the broken neutral? Was it connected to the switch?

Is there a chance this switch is a three way?  Two switches controlling one device.  Three wires on a switch like that is usually a three way.

Can you try to trace out the cables and look for a hidden junction box? It seems to me that there's something funky here involving either bad 3-way wiring (is the switch a 3-way switch with a differently colored hot screw (black vs brass) and/or no ON/OFF labeling on the toggle) or a very hinky and Code violating tap off a switch loop)?
